# Use installed java version in maven repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

It is a simple question, but I didn't find any good solution.

I have created a maven project that is compatible to java8+. I want that, whenever someone builds the project, maven should use the java installed java version.

In other words, I want soneting like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For JAXB I used the following:

```
<profile>
    <id>java-9+</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>java-8</id>
    <activation>
        <jdk>1.8</jdk>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- add Java 8 dependencies -->
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

It needs to work in cli(`mvn` commands), eclipse and in IntelliJ.

Comment: I do not understand why this should be useful. You have written your code for Java 8. Then just compile with `<source>` and `<target>` set to `1.8`. This does not hinder anybody using Java 11 or Java 12 to use the library.

Comment: I don't want jaxb api in my java-8-compilation because it's already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate a profile based on the JDK:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <jdk>1.7</jdk>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I already did this(see my question). But how can I set my the build jdk to this(`<source>` and `<target>` or `<release>`)

Comment: You know that these two things are not the same? That you can build Java 9 compatible with a JDK 11?

Comment: Yes, this is why I wrote `or`.

Comment: Whether `jaxb-api` is there or not depends on the JDK, not the Java version, right? So using the JDKs for the profiles and setting the `<source>` and `<target>` at `1.8` should be alright. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh I understand I thought the `<jdk>` tag means the version it is built for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While you CAN manage dependencies through [profiles activation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Details_on_profile_activation)

```
<profile>
    <activation>
        <jdk>[9,)</jdk>
    </activation>
```

... for users of your library it would be unclear - either your library was build **with** or **without** jaxb-api.

More clear way would be to build 2 separate modules. For Java 8:

```
<artifactId>yourModule</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Java 8 dependencies -->
</dependencies>
```

And for Java 9+:

```
<artifactId>yourModule-9</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>yourModule</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <excludes>
            <!-- Explicitly exclude all irrelevant dependencies. -->
        </excludes>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This way your users will have clear and predictable dependencies.